# merge data into csv with c#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a scenario where data is read from a database and written to a csv file. The data has 3 columns `Name`, `Date` and `Price`.If the csv doesn't exist, a new file is created and the data is written. If the csv does exist, I have to insert the data relative to the `Date` data already in the csv. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to parse your csv back in a datastructure, append the data from the database and sort on the date. Then overwrite the file with the sorted data.